I can't find the foreign key column in the tables in one-to-one mapping using xml approach
I have bidirectional mapping. these are model classes
public class Address {
private Long aId;
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private String country;
private Employee employee; 
}

public class Employee {

private Long empId;
private String empName;
private String empEmail;
private float empSalary;
private Address address;
}

xml files
Employee
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.raju.hibernate.model.Employee" table="employee">
    <id name="empId" column="eid">
    <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="empName" column="ename"></property>
    <property name="empEmail" column="eemail"></property>
    <property name="empSalary" column="esalary"></property>
    <one-to-one name="address" class="com.raju.hibernate.model.Address" cascade="all" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

Address
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.raju.hibernate.model.Address" table="address">
<id name="aId" >
<column name="eid"/>
<generator class="foreign">
<param name="property">employee</param>
</generator>
</id>
<property name="street" column="estreet"></property>
<property name="city" column="ecity"></property>
<property name="state" column="estate"></property>
<property name="country" column="ecountry"></property>
<one-to-one name="employee"
class="com.raju.hibernate.model.Employee"  constrained="true" cascade="all"/>
 </class>                          
</hibernate-mapping>

when i save the employee or address, i can't find the foreign key column in the table(i'm using sql for database). I need the foreign key column in the address table And when i retrieve the employee object it should get the respective address along with it.
Please give a solution with the same fields.
